# Python: filter python dataframe by time

Tags: python

I have the following data frame with a column **not index** called timestamp.

```
0         2019-09-02 09:14:00.125
1         2019-09-02 09:14:00.125
2         2019-09-02 09:14:00.125
3         2019-09-02 09:14:00.125
4         2019-09-02 09:14:00.125
         
1096674   2019-09-20 16:32:00.157
1096675   2019-09-20 16:34:06.988
1096676   2019-09-20 16:34:15.352
1096677   2019-09-20 16:34:15.352
1096678   2019-09-20 16:34:15.551
Name: Timestamp, Length: 1096679, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to extract all rows between `09:13:00.170` and `11:45:00.234` across all dates within the dataframe.

I tried the following

```
df.loc[(df['Timestamp'] >='09:13:00.170') & (df['Timestamp'] <='11:45:00.234'),:]
```

But it received an empty dataframe in return but the first few rows `09:14:00.xxx` are greater than `09:13:00.170` so they should be included. Yet they are not.

What have I done wrong here ?

Comment: If you want to extract all dates between a time, it will be better to have two diferent columns, one for date and the other one for time, and then filter only the time column

Comment: Can you write it out as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are comparing against a string. You can format string to datetime using `strptime()`.

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-09-02 09:13:00.170', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-09-02 11:45:00.234', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

df[(df['Timestamp'] >=start) & (df['Timestamp'] <= end)]
```

Comment: Thing is my data frame contains different dates. And I want to extract all rows that is between those 2 time points across all dates .

Comment: Yep, i understand it as that. Can I ask what was your output from this? Alternatively you can share a minimal dataset and i can try to replicate your desired result